# Where can I buy the QTP tool?

Tags: testing

I am downloading the trial version of QTP but I cannot find the link to buy the QTP tool.

Where can I buy QTP?

Comment: @Razzie, actually, it is more of a pain than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just contact the vendor directly. I doubt you will be able to just buy it on the Web.

[https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24^1352_4000_100__](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24%5E1352_4000_100__)

Look at the "Contact HP" spot on the top right.

Comment: Don't make it as hard as HP to buy the software, make your link clickable! :p

Comment: I tried, I think Markdown has problems with characters in the URL.

Comment: Hopefully sivaramakrishna has contacted HP by now. If not, follow Bobby's link. If you want to email them for Sales enquiries you'll need an HP Passport by the looks of it (just to make it extra hard), or you can call the sales office at:
India
Phone: (+91) 80 2504-1256

Comment: Character '^' makes problem. You need to encode it properly. I had the same problem when posting other link to HP. issue is described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30379/link-recognition-broken-in-question-and-in-comment-it-works-incorrectly